# Need to change @src of a parent iframe from within child iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I have the following HTML markup (don't ask....)

```
- document  //main site
  - <iframe>  //my site
    - <iframe>  //site within my site
      - <frame>
        - <a onclick="JavaScript:parent.parent.location.href='http://bla.com;return false;'">
```

Basically, main site is calling my site in an iframe.  I, in turn, also have an iframe on my site where I'm calling 3rd site.  The third site has a frameset with a frame in it that has a link.  When clicking on this link, it has to change the url of my site.  My site and my child site are on the same domain.  When I'm running my site as "stand-alone" (not in iframe) the above code works fine in all browsers.

Once I open my site in an iframe of the main site, it looks like the above code is trying to change the source of the main site.  In FireFox I get a console message "Access to property denied".  In IE it opens up a new window with my site not in the main site anymore.

What is the correct JavaScript to change the @src attribute on my site when I'm within an iframe?

Answer (score 2):

You are banging your head against the wall that is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) here. This is XSS country and strictly forbidden, no way around it, unless both domains agree to talk together.

You can read more about [cross domain communication using iframes](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes), but again, unless the different domain agree to talk together, you are out of luck.

Although this might seem frustrating, be glad of this rule next time you use homebanking ;)

Comment: Martin, as I always understood it, both iframe site and parent site need to be on the same domain.  Which is the case for me.  The main site is on different domain, which I thought is fine, since I'm not messing with the main site's URL.  Am I wrong?  Do all 3 have to be on the same domain then?

Comment: if all the iframes are running pages from same document.domain they should be able to talk weather or not they live in a page from another domain, as log as they are nested... but tbh, this is a grey area, and browsers may just decide that if all the pages, inner and outer alike are not from the same domain then cross frame communication is a no-go.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this

```
<document> //main site
  <iframe id="my_iframe"> //your site
     <iframe> //site within your site
       <frame>
         <a onclick="JavaScript:Top.document.getElementById('my_iframe').location.href='http://bla.com;return false;'">
```

Top refers to the main window, and then getElementById('my_iframe') will give you your iframe element.

Comment: Interesting thought.  I'll give it a try a little later.  Thanks!

Comment: arifshaikh, I will accept it once I try and it works.  We are in a "code freeze" kind of situation at the moment, so I can't really try it right now.  Although, not a high priority, but the issue is still there.  So, I'll have to come back here in a few days.  Again, thank you for the answer and sorry for the delay on my end.

Comment: No issues, one more thing, if the location.href doesn't work for the iframe, try to change its src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're trying to do *communication between different pages*. 
You may take a look this API: [HTML5 Cross Document Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging)

Basically, if you want to tell the parent iframe to navigate to a certain url, you can do this:

---

In the *site within my site* html:

```
// onclick of your anchor, post message (an event) with an expected origin
window.postMessage("http://bla.com", "www.sitewithinmysite.com");
```

In *my site* html:

```
// listen to the event "message"
window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, true);
function messageHandler(e) {
    // only recognize message from this origin
    if (e.origin === "www.sitewithinmysite.com") {
        // then you can navigate your page with the link passed in
        window.location = e.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't even call any JavaScript on "mysite" from withing mysite's child site.  It also denies the permission.

Comment: @Dimskiy you shouldn't. That's why you need to post a "message" event instead of directly calling any Javascript on the parent. Note that the 2 blocks of code examples should be written _not_ in the same frame

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have the pages communicate using AJAX.  Have the site that needs to change its URL listen by long polling to to a node.js server.